# Can a trigger on a table with a primary key ever be fired with the same primary key appearing twice in either the inserted or deleted table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

If I have a table, `T`, with a primary key, `ID`,

```
CREATE TABLE T (
    ID INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Data BIT NOT NULL DEFAULT (0)
)
```

and create an after insert trigger on it

```
CREATE TRIGGER T_Trigger ON T 
FOR INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    -- Trigger body
END
```

is it ever possible that the `INSERTED` table will have duplicate values for the `ID` column? Or for the `DELETED` table to have duplicate values for the `ID` column?

*Clearly it's possible for the `ID` to appear once in each of the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables.*

I can't imagine a DML statement that could lead to a trigger firing with the same primary key occurring twice in either the `INSERTED` or `DELETED` table. Even `MERGE` is carefully documented to say that "The MERGE statement cannot update the same row more than once, or update and delete the same row." The `PRIMARY KEY` constraint on `ID` and the limited power of each DML statement seem like they should combine to keep it unique in each trigger firing.

Comment: I think No, its not possible for a Primary key column to have duplicates in inserted or deleted tables.

Answer (score 0):

No. The INSERTED and DELETED tables are the final (i.e. "after") state of the operation, in terms of FOR / AFTER triggers.  For INSTEAD OF triggers, the INSERTED and DELETED tables are what would have been the final state.  Well, the DELETED table is really the prior state of those rows whereas INSERTED is the current state.